# Fetching parent process Id from child process

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

I create a child process using CreateProcess API. From the child process I need to fetch the parent's process id.

If my process tree have a child and a grand child. I need to fetch the top most parent's process id from the grand child as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the Native API and `GetProcAddress` to find the address of `NtQueryInformationProcess`.

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    NTSTATUS ExitStatus;
    PPEB PebBaseAddress;
    ULONG_PTR AffinityMask;
    KPRIORITY BasePriority;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    HANDLE InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
} PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PPROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;

NTSYSCALLAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtQueryInformationProcess(
    __in HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    __in PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS ProcessInformationClass,
    __out_bcount(ProcessInformationLength) PVOID ProcessInformation,
    __in ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
    __out_opt PULONG ReturnLength
    );

PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION basicInfo;

NtQueryInformationProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), ProcessBasicInformation, &basicInfo, sizeof(basicInfo), NULL);
// My parent PID (*) is in basicInfo.InheritedFromUniqueProcessId
```

To get the grandparent PID, open the parent process using the parent PID and call `NtQueryInformationProcess` again on the parent process.

Note * - Strictly speaking, the parent process (the process which created the child process) is not actually recorded. `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` just gives you the process from which attributes were inherited. But this is very rarely a problem.

Alternatively, if you don't like the Native API, use [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489.aspx) with `TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS`, which gives you the required information, except that you'll have to search through the list.

Comment: On MSDN, the NtQueryInformationProcess documentation mentions PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, but it doesn't have InheritedFromUniqueProcessId. Is this specific to a certain Windows version? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: NtQueryInformationProcess is now marked as obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

wj32's answer should do what you need, but I figured I'd mention another way in case anyone else needs a ancestor at a different level. You can also take a snapshot enumerate the process tree and navigate the ancestors until you reach whatever level you're looking to reach as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The following example gets the process ID of the parent process (the process started the current one):

```
// Speed up build process with minimal headers.
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Macros for prettier code. */
#ifndef MAX_PATH
#   define MAX_PATH _MAX_PATH
#endif

// Search each process in the snapshot for id.
BOOL FindProcessID(HANDLE snap, DWORD id, LPPROCESSENTRY32 ppe)
{
    BOOL fOk;
    ppe->dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    for (fOk = Process32First( snap, ppe ); fOk; fOk = Process32Next( snap, ppe ))
        if (ppe->th32ProcessID == id)
            break;
    return fOk;
}

// Obtain the process and thread identifiers of the parent process.
BOOL ParentProcess(LPPROCESS_INFORMATION ppi)
{
    HANDLE hSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    THREADENTRY32   te;
    DWORD id = GetCurrentProcessId();
    BOOL fOk;

    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS|TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, id );

    if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return FALSE;

    FindProcessID( hSnap, id, &pe );
    if (!FindProcessID( hSnap, pe.th32ParentProcessID, &pe ))
    {
        CloseHandle( hSnap );
        return FALSE;
    }

    te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
    for (fOk = Thread32First( hSnap, &te ); fOk; fOk = Thread32Next( hSnap, &te ))
        if (te.th32OwnerProcessID == pe.th32ProcessID)
            break;

    CloseHandle( hSnap );

    ppi->dwProcessId = pe.th32ProcessID;
    ppi->dwThreadId = te.th32ThreadID;

    return fOk;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION parentInformation;
    if(!ParentProcess(&parentInformation)) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Fatal: Could not get parent information.\n"));
        return 1;
    }
    _tprintf(TEXT("Parent Process ID: %ul\n"), parentInformation.dwProcessId);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no standard way to find the grandparent process of the current process.  Finding the parent process is normal, but not the grandparent.  If you really need that information, then the parent process has to educate their child about the parent's own parent process - rather like real life where parents have to teach their kids about life in general.

How the communication occurs depends on whether the process is merely replicating itself (forking), or whether it is also executing some other process.  If the processes are merely forking, the parent simply needs to set an appropriate variable.  If the processes are executing other programs, then you need to look at an environment variable or a command line argument to relay the information

Comment: If I leave grandparent and just wanted to find parent's prrocess ID, how could i do.

Comment: @Beetles: In Unix, you'd use `getppid()`.  If you have the Unix services available on your Windows box, then you can use it there, too.  Otherwise, you might find that `_getppid()` is available and works, but there is probably also a native WinAPI call that does the same job - I don't know what it is and my Google-fu seems to have deserted me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C program to get the parent process id (with only one loop on processes in total).
The function GetParentProcessId() returns the Windows parent process id in its out parameter "parent_process_id".

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Find a process with a given id in a snapshot
BOOL FindProcessID(HANDLE snap, DWORD id, LPPROCESSENTRY32 ppe)
{
  BOOL res;
  ppe->dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); // (mandatory)
  res = Process32First(snap, ppe); 
  while (res) {
    if (ppe->th32ProcessID == id) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    res = Process32Next(snap, ppe);
  }
  return FALSE;
}

// Get the parent process id of the current process
BOOL GetParentProcessId(DWORD* parent_process_id)
{
  HANDLE hSnap;
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
  DWORD current_pid = GetCurrentProcessId();

  // Take a snapshot of all Windows processes
  hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hSnap) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Find the current process in the snapshot
  if (!FindProcessID(hSnap, current_pid, &pe)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Close the snapshot
  if (!CloseHandle(hSnap)) {
    return FALSE;    
  }

  *parent_process_id = pe.th32ParentProcessID;
  return TRUE;
}
```