# Microsoft.Web.Administration to find Kestrel processes behind IIS reverse proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm writing a program to monitor web application performance, mostly CPU use and break down per application pool / site.

Using `Microsoft.Web.Administration` I've been able to get a list of application pools, the worker processes, the process IDs and processes with a performance counter to measure those.

However, the IIS `w3wp.exe` processes created by the app pools aren't the actual executing code when using .NET Core and kestrel as the actual web server.

Obviously, I could hard code / config file a bunch of process names and setup a performance monitor on those however a) this doesn't allow for any dynamic updates and b) doesn't tie back to a specific site or app pool.

I've been unable to find the link between the IIS site and the Kestrel server running for that site - I can get the `web.config` and then the process path from there, which will but only if the apps have the different names, as we can't get a process ID from this?

Is there a `Microsoft.Web.Administration` type system for Kestrel?

Comment: You need to find child processes.  So if you have the process ID for w3wp.exe then the children are the processes with a PPID (parent process id) that matches the PID of w3wp.exe.  There also may be other descendants.

Comment: Ah, so I need to get all the processes, then find those with the parent ID - I was looking for Children!

Comment: Windows doesn't make it easy.

Comment: Indeed! However, from the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class there's no PPID or Parent anything... Would they have the same session ID??

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020430/how-to-get-ppid

Comment: @jdweng That's awesome - add an answer and some upvotes are coming your way! Windows only but it's IIS so must be Windows only ;)