# Check if program is runned trough another one

Tags: c++, windows

So my question is as follows: I have a program Main.exe(wich starts the game), i have a dll attached to it so i can load some functions. I have another program called StartGame.exe(launcher+autoupdater), now the question is, how can i make a function to make sure that Main.exe is runned only from StartGame.exe when the client pressed START?
I cannot modify either Main.exe, nor StartGame.exe... I have made some simple check as follows:

```
if(FindWindow(NULL,"LiveMU") == NULL) //LiveMU is the name of window StartGame.exe
{
    MessageBoxA(0,"English: Please use the Launcher! \nRomanian: Va rugam sa folositi Launcher-ul!", TitleMsgBox,MB_ICONERROR);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

The problem is, that if they open startgame.exe, and leave it in the tray, they can load Main.exe without a problem. The MAIN problem is, if i cannot protect somehow Main.exe from launching without the launcher, clients/players use a cheat program loading Main.exe(injecting it or something, i don't really know as it just disappears and i can't find it)

LE: I cannot add command line arguments to StartGame.exe because it`s heavy protected...

Comment: Use a "secret" / internal command line option that is passed from "StartGame.exe" to "Main.exe", exit "Main.exe" immediately if that option is not passed. If a user starts Main.exe (say by double click, command line etc.) the option will not be present and it won't run.

Comment: I allready said, i cannot modify/add/alter StartGame.exe because it`s protected with VMProtect... i cannot pass a command line argument :(

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that part. I think there is no 100% reliable way in general, much less so if you try to control this dependency "from outside" the two programs...

Comment: Maybe some protection againts other stuff ataching to the Main.exe? I cannot find how the cheat(elite clicker) attaches to the game, i think it uses winapi...

Comment: You are asking about problem Y, but what you're really trying to solve is problem X, for which problem Y is just your approach to so solve it. Why not tell us about problem X in a different question? ("How can I avoid players cheating?") The solution might be completely different...

Comment: I can avoid players cheating, i have made a compete antihack system, but i cannot block this certain hack... it loads into the game and dissapears, that`s why i am trying to run the Main.exe trough StartGame.exe. You see, when you run that cheat, you must select the Main.exe Path, then press start, after that there is nothing i can do to detect it :(

Answer (score 1):

The standard Windows API does not allow you to directly find the parent of a process. But hopefully according to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321914/fetching-parent-process-id-from-child-process), you have 2 other solutions (provided the parent process is not already terminated ...) :

- use the native API. The function `NtQueryInformationProcess` can directly give you the information. but beware :

  - you have no import library so you must use explicitely call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`
  - the parent process id is the undocumented field referenced Reserved3 in Microsoft SDK
  - Microsoft warns that this function is not part of public API and may change in future versions.

  If you still want to use it here is a full example getting the parent process executable name (you will have to link with `psapi.lib`):

  ```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <psapi.h>
  #include <TCHAR.h>

  typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION {
      PVOID Reserved1;
      PVOID PebBaseAddress;
      PVOID Reserved2[2];
      ULONG_PTR UniqueProcessId;
      PVOID Reserved3;
  } PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;

  DWORD getParentProcessId(HANDLE process) {
      LONG (WINAPI *NtQueryInformationProcess)(HANDLE ProcessHandle,
          ULONG ProcessInformationClass, PVOID ProcessInformation,
          ULONG ProcessInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength) = NULL;
      HMODULE ntDll = ::LoadLibrary(_T("NTDLL.DLL"));
      FARPROC ntQueryInformationProcess = ::GetProcAddress(ntDll,
          "NtQueryInformationProcess");
      NtQueryInformationProcess =
          (LONG (WINAPI *)(HANDLE,ULONG,PVOID,ULONG,PULONG))ntQueryInformationProcess;
      if (NtQueryInformationProcess == NULL) {
          ::FreeLibrary(ntDll);
          return -1;
      }
      PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pi;
      ULONG piLen;
      NtQueryInformationProcess(process, 0, &pi, sizeof(pi), & piLen);
      DWORD ppid = (DWORD) pi.Reserved3;
      ::FreeLibrary(ntDll);
      return ppid;
  }

  int main() {
      DWORD cr;
      HANDLE proc = ::GetCurrentProcess();
      DWORD ppid = getParentProcessId(proc);

      HANDLE pproc = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, ppid);
      TCHAR pFile[MAX_PATH];
      cr = ::GetModuleFileNameEx(pproc, NULL, pFile, sizeof(pFile));
      ::CloseHandle(pproc);
      if (cr == 0) {
          LPTSTR pBuff;
          DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
          ::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, NULL, error, 0,
              (LPWSTR) &pBuff, 1, NULL);
          ::MessageBox(NULL, pBuff, _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
      }
      ::MessageBox(NULL, pFile, _T("Parent process"), MB_OK);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- if you do not like using poorly documented native API functions, you can use the toolhelp32 library : the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` creates a snapshot of all running processes, that you can browse with `Process32First` and `Process32Next`. Hopefully, you get (documented) `PROCESSENTRY32` structures containing executable name, process id and process parent id. It is heavily documented, and you will easily find many examples on StackOverflow (see referenced question)

Comment: Thank you sir, i will try this. But i allready have a SystemProcessesScan() and ScanProcessMemory(HANDLE hProcess)  with a defined list of executables dumps. It cannot detect this cheat. I tryed tracing it, take a closer look but nothing. In previous versions of this hack, the program masked itself as rundll32.dll so it was easy for me to detect it, and close it by it`s pid. But the new version is killing me and others too :( This is the program(hack): http://www.filedropper.com/muautoclicker maybe if you have some time you can take a look...

Comment: @Mr.Mecanik This posts answers the question *how to see what program launched another one*. But for the real problem of avoiding cheating, it is really a dirty hack and you should consider in a future version passing a secret, or better a hash of that secret and the time of launching to have a unique token.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but please if you have time, can you take a look at the cheat? it`s really advanced and interesting...

Comment: @Mr.Mecanik : it looks like an interesting problem, but DevSolar was right, I don't think it only depends on finding how a program was launched ... and I'm not sure it is really on-topic here :-(. My advice : clearly analyse how muautoclicker interacts with your program, but if it send keystrokes and mouse clicks to your program via the API, it will really be hard, to identify that !

Comment: I have managed to block some keys used by that, but that is not the main problem, the cheat has special commands like: //multihit, //stealth, if you type those in-game. I cannot block those because i don`t know how. Anyway the program send packets to the game, maybe if i could block that uhm